# Sig Tests for weighted means

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, weights

I got the challenge to integrate a test of significance into a Tableau dashboard. The dashboard shows weighted means for metrics such as income, age, etc. for two groups that can be defined by different filter options. The differences between the weighted means of both groups shall be calculated on the fly in the dashboard.

To account for the weighting effect I wanted to apply a formula that considers the effective sample size (see first image below) with the effective sample size (e) being calculated by as follows:

[image]

[image]

Unfortunately, it's not manageable to program these calculations into the dashboard and I'm therefore looking for an easier approach. That will of course come with some limitations that I'd like to get your perspective on.

Would it be possible to use the standard t-test but with the weighted means and the unweighted Ns?

Thanks for your help!